# QGIS Server, REQUEST=GetCapabilities not working

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, docker, nginx

I installed the QGIS Server example on my Synology by this link:
https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/server_manual/containerized_deployment.html#simple-docker-images
but I got this error:

```
[error] 9#9: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.18.0.1, server: 172.18.0.3, request: "GET /cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities HTTP/1.1", host: "mynas:8990"
```

Testing delivers this message:

```
root@qgis-server:/home/qgis# /usr/lib/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi

Application path not initialized
Application path not initialized
Application path not initialized
Application path not initialized
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
Warning 1: Unable to find driver ECW to unload from GDAL_SKIP environment variable.
Warning 1: Unable to find driver ECW to unload from GDAL_SKIP environment variable.
Warning 1: Unable to find driver JP2ECW to unload from GDAL_SKIP environment variable.
"Loading native module /usr/lib/qgis/server/libdummy.so"
"Loading native module /usr/lib/qgis/server/liblandingpage.so"
"Loading native module /usr/lib/qgis/server/libwcs.so"
"Loading native module /usr/lib/qgis/server/libwfs.so"
"Loading native module /usr/lib/qgis/server/libwfs3.so"
"Loading native module /usr/lib/qgis/server/libwms.so"
"Loading native module /usr/lib/qgis/server/libwmts.so"
Content-Length: 0
Location: http:/index.json
Server:  QGIS FCGI server - QGIS version 3.28.2-Firenze
Status:  302

root@qgis-server:/home/qgis#
```

nginx is working good, but
http://mynas:8990/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
Gives me:
404 Not Found
nginx/1.13.12

Answer (score 1):

Problem was nginx.config,
this works good:

containername:qgis-server

```
server {
  listen 80;

   charset utf-8;

location  / {
    proxy_buffers 16 16k;
    proxy_buffer_size 16k;
    gzip off;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass qgis-server:XXXX; # XXXX is portnumber
  }
}
```